# Why does Jenkins not recognize a module which works on the same version of python on my local machine?

Tags: python, jenkins, import

I have a script which works fine on the terminal. I'm trying to tie it to a jenkins job, which essentially only needs to run the python script. So I've written a little shell command at the bottom which calls the script.

However, when it runs, it throws the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named request
```

It's coming from this line:

```
import urllib.request
```

I've tried changing the shebang from python2.7 to python3, but then I get the same error but for the pkg_resources module, which sits right below the first one.

```
import urllib.request
from pkg_resources import parse_version
```

Seems like it should be an easy fix but it's not so far. Does anyone know what I need to do to get Jenkins to recognize these python modules? Again, no problems importing either of these modules on my Terminal.

Comment: Note that `urllib.request` only exists on Python 3, and `pkg_resources` is not part of the standard library on either Python 2 *or* Python 3.  What platform is your Jenkins slave running on?

Comment: Pretty sure it's Linux

Comment: Maybe you need to do an `apt-get install python3-setuptools` as part of the Jenkins setup? Or whatever the equivalent is for the target Linux distro. (The `pkg_resources` module comes from `setuptools`.)